# What activation function for producing positive output beside sigmoid?

Tags: neural-networks

I have a regression neural network that is intended to produce a positive output. I am wondering what other activation functions that I can use to produce positive value that does not include 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The softplus function $h(x) = \log\left(1 + \exp(x)\right)$ is a smooth approximation to the ReLU and is non-negative (neglecting numerical error; add a constant if it underflows).
2. Choose some $c >0$ and use the activation $f(x) = \text{ReLU}(x) + c$. This is always positive, and preserves some of the nice qualities of ReLUs (though it obviously does not preserve the sparsity property).
3. You can do a similar thing as (1) for the ELU function if you choose $c> 1$.
4. Basically the same idea as (1) is to define a different kind of ReLU: $g(x) = \max\{x, c\}$.
5. $\tanh(x) + 1$ is also positive for real $x$, if you want to use $s$-shaped functions.